# Добавление элементов в массив

Tags: javascript

```
var arr1=[3, 'a', 'a', 'a', 2, 3, 'a', 3, 'a', 2, 4, 9, 3];
count=Object();
for(var i=0;i<arr1.length;i++)
{
    if(!(arr1[i] in count))
    {
        count[arr[i]]=1;       
    }
    else if (arr[i] in count) {
        count[arr[i]]++;
    }
    alert(count[arr[i]]);
}
```

Каким образом следует добавлять элементы в ассоциативный массив? Так не получается, а как иначе не знаю.

Comment: push() не подходит ? [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push][1]


  [1]: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Comment: http://javascript.ru/Array/splice

Comment: push() добавляет массив в массиву если я не ошибаюсь

Comment: @Alex9, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение.

Answer (score 3):

В javascript нет ассоциативных массивов. Есть объекты. Не надо использовать конструктор Object. Используйте литерал {}.

```
var myObject = {};
myObject.myNewPropoperty /*или myObject['myNewPropoperty'] */ = 'something';
```

В вашем примере переменная arr1 не определена. Из за этого ошибка. Может вопрос стоит как то уточнить?

Comment: arr не определена, arr1 определена.

Comment: В javascript нет ассоциативных массивов. Теперь есть - Map и WeakMap